# Creating Folder using REST and JavaScript

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, ajax

I'm trying to create a Folder in a SharePoint Image library. I found an [answer here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110025/copying-files-and-folders-via-rest-javascript) but I can't seem to get it to work

```
var web = 'my relative path to the current web';
var lib = 'name of the image library';
var foldername = 'jasonscript';

var postData = JSON.stringify({ 
    '__metadata'        : { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 
    'ServerRelativeUrl' : lib + '/' + foldername 
});

var pCreate = jQuery.ajax({
    'url'        : web + '/_api/Web/Folders',
    'type'       : 'POST',
    'data'       : postData,
    'headers'    : { 
                    'accept'          : 'application/json; odata=verbose', 
                    'content-type'    : 'application/json; odata=verbose',
                    'X-RequestDigest' : $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
                   }
}); 

jQuery.when(pCreate).always(function (data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

This returns the following error:

```
{
    "error":{
        "code":"-2130247139, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message":{
            "lang":"en-US",
            "value":"(null) \"██████/██████/██████\" not found."
        }
    }
}
```

where the redacted values are the web, lib and foldername values.

I know the folder doesn't exist. I'm trying to create it!

**Update**

I'm trying to run this code in a Content Editor Web Part (i.e. Not an app)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about using the Add method:

If for example using SiteCollectionDocuments in a Site Collection

```
'url' : _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Folders/add('SiteCollectionDocuments/newfolder')"
```

This shouldn't require the data payload 'postData'.

See more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841(v=office.15).aspx#bk_FolderCollectionAdd

---

Complete code used:

```
var pCreate = jQuery.ajax({
"url"        : _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Folders/add('SiteCollectionDocuments/newfolder')",
"type"       : "POST",
"headers"    : { 
                "accept"          : "application/json; odata=verbose", 
                "content-type"    : "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest" : $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
               }
}); 

jQuery.when(pCreate).always(function (data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Is this function only for SharePoint apps? I'm just running JavaScript within a Content Editor web part and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: It works. You should be able to use in a console command on the page not restricted to Apps. But the path was incorrect, needed to remove leading /. Have edited post.

Comment: This works -- there is no siteAbsoluteUrl property in _spPageContextInfo for 2010, but there is in 2013. Just ensure the folder URL parameter is correct as in Vadim's answer.

Comment: Good to know RE: 2010 property!

Comment: Confirmed this works. +1 because it seems like better use of the SharePoint API

Comment: It's strange. The `Add` method will only accept values wrapped in single quotes. Wrapping them in double quotes (as I had tried originally) doesn't work

Comment: what is #__REQUESTDIGEST?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the correct `ServerRelativeUrl` has been provided, the following formats could be specified:

- Server-relative URL: `/<web url>/<list url>/<folder url>`
- Site-relative URL: `<list url>/<folder url>`

For example, to create a folder named `Orders` in a `Documents` library in a sub site `Projects`, you could specify:

```
'ServerRelativeUrl' : 'Shared Documents/Orders'
```

or

```
'ServerRelativeUrl' : '/project/Shared Documents/Orders'
```

Comment: This answer was the correct one. My image library was called "MyImages" but I had renamed it to "My Images" (with a space). Once I corrected this, it started working

Comment: This is something I glossed over in my answer that was linked to in the original question -- I've added a bit about it and linked here as well because I think it makes the answer I gave in the other thread more complete!