# Creating folder in 2013 with REST API

Tags: 2013, rest, folder

Related to question [Creating Folder using REST and JavaScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110183/creating-folder-using-rest-and-javascript), I used 3 approaches to create folder with REST API (native C++ casablanca lib):

```
request.set_method(methods::POST);
request.headers().add(U("X-RequestDigest"), my_digest);
request.headers().add(U("content-type"), U("application/json; odata=verbose"));
```

1. Works OK

   ```
   request.set_request_uri(web::uri::encode_uri(U("/_api/Web/Folders/add('/Shared Documents/new folder created')")));
   ```
2. HTTP 400 Bad request (example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553%28v=office.15%29.aspx))

   ```
   request.set_request_uri(web::uri::encode_uri(U("/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents')/Folders")));
   request.set_body(U("{ '__metadata':{ 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl':'new folder created' }"));
   ```
3. HTTP 400 Bad request (example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553%28v=office.15%29.aspx))

   ```
   request.set_request_uri(web::uri::encode_uri(U("/_api/Web/Folders/")));
   request.set_body(U("{ '__metadata':{ 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl':'Shared Documents/new folder created' }"));
   ```

Are there any ideas why only #1 works?
Can anyone confirm that it works from another environments like JavaScript?

Comment: tried set Header to request ?

Comment: Yes, headers are set - I wrote that #1 works. It wouldn't without headers. But anyway - I will add those code to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SP.Folder.serverRelativeUrl property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247005(v=office.15).aspx) accepts the following formats:

- `/Site_Name/SubSite_Name/Library_Name/File_Name`
- `Library_Name/File_Name`

Assuming the following structure:

```
/ (Root site)

   News sub site

     Documents library
```

the following examples demonstrate how to create a Folder:

### Case 2

**Example 1**

Url:  `http://<server>/news/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/news/Shared Documents')/Folders`

Body: `{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': '/news/Shared Documents/New Folder'};`

**Example 2**

Url:  `http://<server>/news/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents')/Folders`

Body: `{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': 'Shared Documents/New Folder'};`

### Case 3

**Example 1**

Url:  `http://<server>/news/_api/web/folders/`

Body: `{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': '/news/Shared Documents/New Folder'};`

**Example 2**

Url:  `http://<server>/news/_api/web/folders/`

Body: `{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': 'Shared Documents/New Folder'};`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see the value of the `ServerRelativeUrl` parameter in #2 and #3 is not correct. See the examples on MSDN you reffered to. In #2 it is simply the folder name, in #3 the leading slash is missing. Should be `'/Shared Documents/new folder created'` instead, the same value yuo use in the working #1.

I suggest you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or another network sniffing tool to see the possibe error details returned by the server over the general `HTTP 400 Bad Request` response status message.

Comment: You are right about #3. Regarding #2 - after server restart it occasionally stared working! I guess that it is doesn't matter how you call folders creating - from root Folders collection and pass long path to new folder, or just pass a new folder name but for Folders collection of concrete parent folder