# Creating new Sharepoint Document folders and sub folders programatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, php

How to create New Document Directories and sub directories programatically in SharePoint Site Document Library using PHP REST API calls. Any example is appreciated.

Comment: I'll provide some resources in 2 stages. 1 representing how to use the REST API with PHP. You may refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545824/how-to-connect-sharepoint-with-php Or https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.vgrem.com/2014/05/31/sharepoint-online-client-php/amp/ 2: resources for the REST API and creating folders: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137560/create-a-document-libary-with-sharepoint-rest-api https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125047/creating-folder-in-2013-with-rest-api

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/81023)