# Create folder in list using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

Below code goes to success for creating folder in sharepoint list, but when I see it in list, its not created.

```
var url_web = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var docLibrary = "Location_Ref";
var folderUrl =  docLibrary + "/" + "Doc-Location3";
var folderPayload = { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': "folderPayload "}; 

  $.ajax({
        url: url_web + "/_api/web/folders",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(folderPayload),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
success: function(){
alert("success");
},
error: function(){
alert("error");
}
    });
```

what to do now?

Comment: is the option to turn on folders turned on in the advanced settings?

Comment: yes it is turned on

Comment: Are you sure this line is correct? `var folderPayload = { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': "folderPayload "};` folderPayload isn't a server relative url no matter how you slice it, also needs a beginning slash `/`

Comment: So, what should I do then, what should I try instead of it.
I have tried with giving the actual path also

Comment: Look at this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110183/creating-folder-using-rest-and-javascript

Comment: I have done it for library, but for list I think it is different

Comment: I am not 100% sure (it is SharePoint after all) You can't create Folders in a List, the Folder DocumentType Type can only be created in Libraries

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman You can create a folder in the list.  There is an option in the advanced setting 'Make "New Folder" command available?'