# Creating folder in SharePoint Library using Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, jquery-ajax

I want to create a folder inside "Communications" document library in below site using rest api.

https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SP

Can you please assist on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Folders` endpoint something like below:

```
_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Folders/add('Communications/NewFolderName')"
```

**Note**: You need to pass the `ServerRelativeUrl` inside the `add` method.

**Official documentation**: [Working with folders by using REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-folders-by-using-rest).

**Similar question**: [Creating Folder using REST and JavaScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110183/creating-folder-using-rest-and-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @Ganesh  i am able to create a folder but now i want to create a new folder inside a pre-existing folder of a list. How i can achieve that?

Comment: You need pass the ServerRelativeUrl of the existing folder in  `add`.